# Google Ads 8.0 Interstitial SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, admob, swift5, google-mobile-ads

Seems like there isn't many examples of using Google MobileAdsSDK 8.0 (iOS) with SwiftUI.
So far I have a class `Interstitial`

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit
    
final class Interstitial:NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate{
    var interstitial:GADInterstitialAd!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        LoadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func LoadInterstitial(){
        let req = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: "...", request: req) { ad, error in
            self.interstitial = ad
            self.interstitial.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
        
    }
    
    func showAd(){
        if self.interstitial != nil {
            let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
            self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
        }
    }
    
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        LoadInterstitial()
    }
}
```

In my SwiftUI view i create a local variable `Interstitial`, and when an action is performed I call the `showAd()` function however when the ad displays it stops the code immediately following the `showAd()` call from running. So I think I need to somehow call `showAd()` and once the ad is dismissed then perform the remainder of my code in the view. As you can see above the `Interstitial` class is the delegate, but how do I "alert" my SwiftUI view that the ad was dismissed so I can execute the rest of the code? Below is my View.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var interstitial : Interstitial = Interstitial()

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //... Display content
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            HStack{
                Button(action: actionSheet) {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
                
            }
        )
    }
    
    func showAd(){
        interstitial.showAd()
    }
    
    func actionSheet() {
        showAd()
        let data = createPDF()
        let temporaryFolder = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
        let fileName = "export.pdf"
        let temporaryFileURL = temporaryFolder.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            try data.write(to: temporaryFileURL)
            let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [try URL(resolvingAliasFileAt: temporaryFileURL)], applicationActivities: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

By adding an excaping closure, you pass a function and perform the needed actions.

```
final class InterstitialAd: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    var completion: () -> Void
    var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd!
    
    init(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        
        super.init()
        
        LoadInterstitialAd()
    }
    
    func LoadInterstitialAd() {
        let req = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: Constants.AdmobIDs.saveImageBlockID, request: req) { ad, error in
            self.interstitial = ad
            self.interstitial.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
        
    }
    
    func show() {
        if self.interstitial != nil {
            let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
            self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
        }
    }
    
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        LoadInterstitialAd()
        completion()
    }
}
```